# Is it less efficient to initialize iteration counters in for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, optimization

What I'm asking is if it is less efficient to write

```
for (int i=0; i<end; i++) {}
```

instead of

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<end; i++) {}
```

I'm sure it makes no difference if this is the only code being executed but what if you have more loops down the road and you declare them the former way? Then the variable `i` will be deallocated and reallocated again, instead of simply being set to zero as it would happen with the latter code. This will mean a performance hit. This is probably still almost negligible, but what if I do this in a nested loop? Then the innermost loop counter will go out of scope every iteration of the outermost loop, and be deallocated, only to be allocated and initialized again, potentially incurring in a substantial performance hit.

Am I right in thinking this, or is the compiler smart enough to optimize this. Moreover, I believe it would be good practice to use the first snippet, as it would ensure that the counter would go out of scope after the loop ended, instead of remaining allocated?

Comment: If it worries you, measure it and see.

Comment: The only difference is scope of the counter being limited to the loop whereas otherwise it is not. That difference usually does not matter, though it may matter if you have a very poor optimizer, or if you reuse/redeclare the name later in the same surrounding scope.

Comment: I am not a specialist here, but compilers are pretty smart about optimizing loops. They do stuff that we probably even haven't thought about, including things like getting rid of loops altogether when possible. One thing that wouldn't surprise me is if loop counter would not be allocated on the stack but in some CPU register. 
Also, keep in mind that allocating and deallocating variables is something that is going on all the time. [1/2]

Comment: Basically any time you are passing a parameter or function result by value you are doing this. That all being said, the best advice is to measure with different optimisation levels and see if it matters anything. [2/2]

Comment: The former is probably *more* likely to ensure that the variable can be kept in a register and not need to be saved across a function call.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers are free to reuse storage from expired variables for future variables.  For an `int`, destroying the old storage is zero cost, as is starting use.  So barring a debug build or an extremely poor quality compiler, `for (int x=0;` is no more expensive than `int x=0; for(;`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of your worries is about the following case:

```
for(int k=0; k<INT_MAX; k++) {
    for (int i=0; i<end; i++) {}
}
```

Compilers would allocate space for `i` when the enclosing function or scope is first entered instead of allocating and deallocating them for each iteration of `k` loop. For reusing variables, see @Yakk's answer. Believe me, compilers are much more smarter than you and me.